# Bmw E46: strange problems with automatically closing windows and broken light warning

Tags: electrical, bmw

I have had a couple of strange problems and I can't really make sense of it. When I parked the car, I locked the doors as always with the windows closed (I am absolutely sure about this; it was freezing cold outside). When I came back, the car was still locked, but the front windows were down. I immediately checked whether anything was stolen, but that was not the case and there were also no signs of forced entry. When I wanted to start the car, I had a left rear light warning, but all rear lights (brake light and indicators included) still worked perfectly. 5 minutes later, the warning went away, only to come back on when I started the car the next time (it's still active now). Does anyone have any ideas what the problem might be?

Perhaps I should also mention that I have had some 'mild' engine problems with, what I believe to be irregular fuel injection (which I have already addressed by this time and it seems to have helped), but I cannot see how this engine problem could be related to windows coming down on their own and a faulty rear light warning, which is more electronics related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a problem with a module.  There is a feature in most BMW's that rolls down all the windows when the unlock button is held but if you are sure you didn't do that then it could be a module.  (Note: some BMWs relock if no doors are open after a specified time period).

Since you also had incorrect rear light warnings at the same time, I would suggest trying to find if the same module does both and if so replace it.

Comment: I am aware of that feature. It could have accidentally rolled down my windows while the button was being pressed down in my pocket, but it takes quite a while for both windows to completely go down, so I doubt it, but I can't rule it out. The module that deals with the windows is the GM5 central locking module, but since everything else that module does still works fine, I doubt it's due to that. I haven't had the window problem anymore, so replacing it is probably unnecessary. [...]

Comment: [...] Since the only issue now seems to be the faulty light warning, I think I will just wait for now to avoid unnecessary costs and repairs. In case the window problem or other problems that could be related to the module come back, I can still replace it.

Answer (score 2):

BMW bulb holders are well known to overheat and deteriorate from the heat. Remove the bulb holders, one at a time and check for discolouration. Replace them if so.